# What does "it's a whole lot of cake with not a lot of icing" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

"That/this/it's a whole lot of cake with not a lot of icing"

I don't have great context for this but I don't know if saying this sentence can be construed as offensive, etc.

Comment: I have never heard it before but it sounds rude to me, the item is a bit basic without any fancey

Comment: yeah, I agree but I've heard this guy use it in like x10 different contexts if someone has experience with this saying id love the insight.

Comment: You clearly do have some context if you've heard it 10 times!

Comment: not a single google hit, so he must have made it up

Comment: @StuartF everytime its different context which is why I'm asking if its a idiom that can just be used to paint with a broad brush

Answer (score 4):

*Icing* is what Americans call *frosting*. 'The icing on the cake' is a fairly common idiom for an addition that makes something nice even better.

Presumably the expression you quote is intended to mean 'a lot of the basic item without much in the way of extras'. It appears to be a fairly mild criticism rather than 'offensive'.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, the icing on the cake is a very fixed idiom. And yes, Kate has it right. The cake is the basic thing and the icing is extra in the expression that guy uses.

Comment: "A whole lot of cake with not a lot of icing" is not a fixed idiom, but English does allow us to make up metaphors as we go along.